# grunt copy moving build folder outside of project

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

Hello I have a file structure that looks like this,

```
|-App
|------|src
|----------|js
|----------|img
|----------|css
|----------|less
|----------|tpl
|----------|index.php
|- Gruntfile.js (withing parent app folder)
|- package.json (withing parent app folder)
```

What I am trying to do is move all the contents of the src folder into a build folder, the build folder gets created but outside of the App folder, and I don't really understand why, secondly when it does copy the src folder it copies the actual src folder, I want to copy all its children but no the parent src folder, and thirdly the copy ignores the index.php file why? Below is my current Gruntfile.js

```
    module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({

      copy: {
        build: {
            cwd: '.',
            src: ['src/*/*'],
            dest: '../build',
            expand: true
        }
      },
      clean: {
        build: {
            cwd: '.',
            src: ['build']
        }
      }

  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');

  grunt.registerTask('move', 'Moves the project to the build folder', ['copy', 'clean']);

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your paths are wrong. Change the `build` options to:

```
build: {
  cwd: '.',
  src: ['src/**/*'],
  dest: './build',
  expand: true
}
```

- `../build` meant the build directory was created in the parent dir (`..` is the parent dir)
- `src/**/*` means recursively copy all files and files of descendent folders.

Comment: Many thanks this has helped but in my build folder I now have the src folder, is there away that I can get only the content of src into the build folder, and not the actual src folder?

Comment: I guess with pwd set to src and src set to **/* yes